# Can't select sibling

Tags: css

I'm trying to use the sibling selectors `+` and/or `~` for the first time:

**HTML**

```
<div id="social">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="follow">Follow us on Twitter</div>
        <img src="images/twitter.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
header #social .wrap .follow {  
    display: none;
}

header #social img:hover ~ .follow{
    display: block
}
```

Basically, by default the message in .follow is not displayed. I would like it to appear when the user hovers over the image. I tried `~` (above) and also `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sibling has to appear after the element, ie

```
<img src="images/twitter.png">
<div class="follow">Follow us on Twitter</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y2AX8/

Comment: Cool thanks! So there is no way to select a sibling that appears before?

Comment: Not with siblings.  Sure you can achieve what you are trying to do via referencing the .wrap instead, though - see: http://jsfiddle.net/y2AX8/1/